# how to get php cli processes share variables via apc

Tags: php, command-line-interface, apc

i have `apc.enable_cli=1` in php.ini for cli;

i tested sharing variables with apc with this script:

```
<?php
$apctest=apc_fetch('apctest');
echo "apctest was " . $apctest;
echo "\n";
if($argc>1){
    $newval=$argv[1];
}else{
    $newval='ok';
}
echo "setting apctest to " . $newval;
echo "\n";
apc_store('apctest',$newval);
sleep(30);
```

i runned it with

```
php test_cli_apc.php > /dev/null &
```

and then within 30 seconds runned

```
php test_cli_apc.php
```

but it has outputted "apctest was " , not "apctest was ok"

i have tried same script with "apc" changed to "apcu" but it also does not work in same way.

Comment: AFAIK APC is only there within the server whilst it is running.  So if you run separate CLI's then the values will not persist.  Use something like memcache which is an external cache.

Comment: Just because a cli process is running, doesn't mean you can run another cli instance and read APC variables. A cli process shares no state or memory with other cli processes. So APC is of no value in CLI processes.